# katalon compare api response with database

Tags: katalon-studio

I am not sure how to link test cases, add more verification.
I am thinking how to link both above, store the API response and after this completed successfully: ID, productid, productinfo.

Then query the database details, store it if possible (I have checkpoint created, not sure if this is the right approach), then verify values from API response same as the database column value.

I have object repository for sets of API message (GET/POST)

1. POST API to insert new product

Then 2 keywords to test the response of API matched the database records

1. connect to API and POST to insert the new product
2. connect to database and Get the table details

I have an individual test case to test the API POST message getting response 200 and run successfully. And another test case to connect to the database and query the table details.

===========
1. add product keyword groovy script

```
package Product
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

    public class API {

        @Keyword
        AddProduct() {

            def result = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject('AddProduct'))

            return result
       }
  }
```

======================================
        2. database groovy script

```
package database
import java.sql.*
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword

public class postgresHandler {

    Connection c = null
    Statement stmt = null

    @Keyword
    public void connectToPostgres(){

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")

            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres?currentSchema=SCHEMA";
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user","postgres");
            props.setProperty("password","postgres");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage())
            System.exit(0)
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully")
    }

    @Keyword
    public void getProduct(){

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")

            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres?currentSchema=SCHEMA";
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user","postgres");
            props.setProperty("password","postgres");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

            c.setAutoCommit(false)
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully")

            stmt = c.createStatement()
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "select * from products.products;" )
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                String id = rs.getString("id")
                String productid = rs.getString("productid")
                String productInfo  = rs.getString("productInfo")

                System.out.println( "ID = " + id )
                System.out.println( "productID = " + productid )
                System.out.println( "productInfo = " + productInfo )

                System.out.println()
            }
            rs.close()
            stmt.close()
            c.close()
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() )
            System.exit(0)
        }
        System.out.println("Operation done successfully")
    }
}
```

=============================================================
3. Test case to call add product keyword groovy script

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject

import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS

result = CustomKeywords.'swisslog.KafkaRest.AddProduct'()

print(result)

WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('AddProduct'))
```

=====================================================

4. Test case to call database groovy script

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.configuration.RunConfiguration
CustomKeywords.'dsdatabase.postgresHandler.connectToPostgres'()
CustomKeywords.'dsdatabase.postgresHandler.getProduct'()
```